# Understanding Ruby Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the best way to learn Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-ruby)
>   [Explain Iterator Syntax on Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293120/explain-iterator-syntax-on-ruby-on-rails)

I'm still learning ruby, ruby on rails and such. I'm getting better at understanding all the ruby and rails syntax but this one has me a little stumped.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @contact_lists }
end
```

respond_to is a method that takes a proceedure, I think.  The two formats look like they may be method calls too, but I don't know.

Comment: Additionally, if you have no intention to return xml contant, you can remove whole "respond_to do .. end" part. Code will only become simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`respond_to` is a method which takes block. The block takes one argument, which here is called `format`.

Now you call two methods on `format`. `html` which you call without arguments. And `xml` which you call with a block.

This block takes no arguments and contains a call to the render method with a hash as an argument. The hash contains the key `:xml` and the value `@contact_lists`.

Answer (score 4):

Yeap, you're right.

Ruby method calls are a bit puzzling at first, because you can ommit the parethesis, and they may receive code blocks.

So, this is the explaination:

```
respond_to do |format|
```

Invoke the method `respond_to`  and pass it a block on what to do with the `format` it will receive.

```
    format.html # index.html.erb
```

With that object called `format`  invoke the method `html`

```
    format.xml  { render :xml => @contact_lists }
```

And the method `xml`  which in turns receive another block ( do / en  and { } , are different syntax to pass block. )

```
end
```

Finish the first block

See [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293120/explain-iterator-syntax-on-ruby-on-rails/3293504#3293504) , [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066703/blocks-and-yields-in-ruby/3066939#3066939)  answers.

Answer (score 3):

I think [this post](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/3/27/web-services-rails-style) can help you.

Also, take a minute to read the [respond_to documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to).
It is worth to know that this method has [changed in Rails 3](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/ClassMethods.html#method-i-respond_to).

> Without web-service support, an action
>   which collects the data for displaying
>   a list of people might look something
>   like this:
>
> ```
> def index
>   @people = Person.find(:all)
> end
> ```
>
> Here’s the same action, with
>   web-service support baked in:
>
> ```
> def index
>   @people = Person.find(:all)
>
>   respond_to do |format|
>     format.html
>     format.xml { render :xml => @people.to_xml }
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> What that says is, "if the client
>   wants HTML in response to this action,
>   just respond as we would have before,
>   but if the client wants XML, return
>   them the list of people in XML
>   format." (Rails determines the desired
>   response format from the HTTP Accept
>   header submitted by the client.)
>
> Supposing you have an action that adds
>   a new person, optionally creating
>   their company (by name) if it does not
>   already exist, without web-services,
>   it might look like this:
>
> ```
> def create
>   @company = Company.find_or_create_by_name(params[:company][:name])
>   @person  = @company.people.create(params[:person])
>
>   redirect_to(person_list_url)
> end
> ```
>
> Here’s the same action, with
>   web-service support baked in:
>
> ```
> def create
>   company  = params[:person].delete(:company)
>   @company = Company.find_or_create_by_name(company[:name])
>   @person  = @company.people.create(params[:person])
>
>   respond_to do |format|
>     format.html { redirect_to(person_list_url) }
>     format.js
>     format.xml  { render :xml => @person.to_xml(:include => @company) }
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: +1 for clarifying how Ruby determines the desired response format!